# Error sip reload linux server

Tags: linux, ubuntu-server

Estoy realizando una configuracion de asterisk en VirtualBox con linux server 20.04.

Ya agregue en los modulos de sip.conf, iax.conf y extensions.conf los numeros de los dispositivos y su contraseña, despues de editar ingreso el comando sip reload en el CLI y me arroja el error mostrado en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He googleado varias posibles soluciones pero no me han funcionado, en algunas dicen que deshabilitar selinum, pero ni si quiera esta instalado.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Revisa si te falto `make samples` y si incluiste el módulo controlador de canal: `chan_sip`.

Comment: @Sal
Y como valido eso, make samples, si lo agregue, pero el modulo chan_sip como lo puedeo validar?

Comment: `*CLI> module show like chan_sip`